# A script with type="text/babel" isn't executing or being requested by chrome, but it works as a "text/javascript" file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying to learn react and have this simple template from the getting started guide:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.9.4/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js has this code:

```
console.log("Works!")
```

But this never runs. In fact, according to the devtools, [it's not even being requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtY5s.png). Changing the `type="text/babel"` to `text/javascript` makes it run, but I can't use any JSX like that. I've also tried inlining the code and it still does not work.

Comment: Having the exact same issue, has anyone actually found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

A little dig in the chrome devtools revealed that due to CORS policy the script request for "main.js" has been blocked. To overcome this you can disable the CORS policy for chrome.

[image: This is the screenshot from the chrome devtools]

TO disable CORS policy you can follow:
[Disable CORS for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) Although it is not recommended.

Simplest thing to do is here is just use a conventional node environment to practice react.

Comment: I have the same issue I'll try to follow the same steps and hopefully it will be solved.

Comment: When I use the parameter ` --disable-web-security` when starting chrome.exe, I cannot log in to the application, so I am unable to use this method.